# Invertible? rewriteable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is as follows:

Let $A$ be an $n$-by-$n$ matrix with the characteristic polynomial $p$.

1. Prove that $A$ is invertible if and only if $p(0) \ne 0$.
2. Let $A$ be invertible. Show that $A^{-1}$ can be rewritten in the form of 
   $$A^{-1}= b_0 I + b_1 A + b_2 A^2 +\cdots +b_{n-1}A^{n-1}. $$

On the first part I would have answered that if $p(0)$ is zero then $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ so it is not invertible so $p(0) \ne 0$.

But I can't find a theory in my book for the second part..

So is my first answer correct and how can I solve the second half of the question?

Comment: look up cayley-hamilton theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to the first part is correct.  Here's a hint for the second part: suppose that
$$
p(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + \cdots + a_n t^n
$$
where $a_0 = p(0) \neq 0$.  Note that $p(A) = 0$.  So, we have
$$
p(A) = a_0 I + a_1 A + \cdots + a_n A^n = 0 \implies\\
a_0 I + A(a_1 I + a_2 A + \cdots + a_n A^{n-1}) = 0
$$